# METEOR: Paste event (client side) to call meteor method

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am attempting to use the following JQuery code to call a Meteor method:

```
$('html').bind('paste', function(e) {
    Meteor.call('click', document.getElementById("box").value);
});
```

I put this code in a script tag in the html and confirmed that the code is called when I need it to be called. However, rather than calling the Meteor method ("click") paste simply pastes the line:

```
Meteor.call('click', document.getElementById("box").value);
```

into the textarea I'm attempting to paste into.

Is there a way to call Meteor Methods from JQuery binds? Or perhaps there is a Meteor event that does this? Either will do! Thanks!

If it helps,

```
document.getElementById("box").value
```

is just a string I am passing into the 'click' method. Also, I am still working on my JQuery skills as you could probably tell.

Comment: Maybe event 'change body' in Template events? Also I can't find events hooks in Meteor docs, but 'paste html' might work, since most of those events work

Comment: I can't seem to get 'change body' or 'change #box' to work. `'change #box': function () {
         Meteor.call('click', $("#box").val());

 }` is what I tried within my Template events.

Comment: And box is textarea?

Comment: Correct. Just a regular old text area. Could Bootstrap be messing with it at all? Just saying anything that could help.

Comment: I don't think so, but change #box should work, weird

Comment: So here is what I have found out. I got the on change event to work, however, it is only fired when you change the contents of the textarea and then click outside of the textarea. Do you get this same result? I need it to be called as the textarea is being changed.

Comment: No, i get It every Time text changes, ofc i use meteor events

Comment: Also, when I type something my event looks like :
`'keyup #text': function() {
            Session.set("search", text.value);

        },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what did the trick:

```
Template.textGoesHere.events({
    'input #thebox': function (e) {
        Meteor.call('click', $("#thebox").val());
    }
});
```

Every time the text area received input, even if text was removed, the Meteor function "input #thebox" is called.

This did exactly what I needed it to!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't rely on 'input' event because as meteor docs says:

> "Other DOM events are available as well, but for the events above, Meteor has taken some care to ensure that they work uniformly in all browsers."

There are also a note:

> "For text fields, use blur or key events to respond to changes."

So I would code this event like this (keydown instead of input):

```
Template.textGoesHere.events({
    'keydown #thebox': function (e) {
        Meteor.call('click', e.target.value);
    }
});
```

Also I've changed value to **e.target.value** because it's already inside event (you don't need to search DOM with jquery)